# MethodAccessException opening View editor in MVC5 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

When I attempt to open a .cshtml view in an MVC5 project, Visual Studio throws an exception and logs an error in my `%AppData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog`.

The top of exception stack trace looks like this:

```
System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost..ctor(System.String, System.String)' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Instrumentation.InstrumentationService..ctor()' failed. 
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost..ctor(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) 
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHost(String virtualPath, String physicalPath)
```

What's gone wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The web.config `configuration/appSettings` key `webpages:Version` value needs to be set correctly. In the instance I found, having a version of `2.0.0.0` caused the exception, and `3.0.0.0` to match MVC5's version of Razor works properly.